# T-SQL: Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, in UPDATE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [LocalizedCountries]
(
    [Guid] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [CustomerLanguageGuid] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [CountryGuid] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [LocalizedCountryName] AddressCountryType NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_LocalizedCountries] PRIMARY KEY ([Guid]),
    CONSTRAINT [TUC_LocalizedCountries_1] UNIQUE ( [CountryGuid], [CustomerLanguageGuid])
)
GO
```

So, there's a constraint `[TUC_LocalizedCountries_1]` which is to assure that each pair of columns `[CountryGuid], [CustomerLanguageGuid]` are unique.

I have a row in the table which has values in all of the table columns.

However, when I'm giving an *UPDATE* statement for that row, it gives me an error related to *INSERT*ing a duplicate value to the table.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[LocalizedCountries]
SET [Guid] = N'591545A9-F2C7-497E-A299-1C8471223CE9',
    [CustomerLanguageGuid] = N'935DE428-12DA-4FD5-9C64-AB87747FA734',
    [LocalizedCountryName] = N'Estonia',
    [CountryGuid] = N'FE73A07D-8505-89C2-450B-4E3F4241F1BB'      
WHERE Guid = N'591545A9-F2C7-497E-A299-1C8471223CE9'
GO
```

Error:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 4
>   Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'TUC_LocalizedCountries_1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.LocalizedCountries'. The duplicate key value is (fe73a07d-8505-89c2-450b-4e3f4241f1bb, 935de428-12da-4fd5-9c64-ab87747fa734).

However, if enter the *UPDATE* command as below, there's no error.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[LocalizedCountries]
SET [Guid] = N'591545A9-F2C7-497E-A299-1C8471223CE9',
    [LocalizedCountryName] = N'Estonia',
    [CountryGuid] = N'FE73A07D-8505-89C2-450B-4E3F4241F1BB'      
WHERE Guid = N'591545A9-F2C7-497E-A299-1C8471223CE9'
```

I am puzzled what causes this error. I have equivalent `LocalizedCities` table with exactly similar structure and constraint, and with that table the error does not show up.

Comment: Well - what is the exact **definition** of that unique constraint that gets violated? Check what that constraint ensures - then maybe you'll understand why it throws this error in your first `UPDATE` statement

Comment: You must already have a different row with countryguid = 'FE73A07D-8505-89C2-450B-4E3F4241F1BB' and customlanguageguid = '935de428-12da-4fd5-9c64-ab87747fa734'

Comment: Why are you updating the Guid column to the same value it already is? You also need to use another column for your clustered index or be prepared for MASSIVE fragmentation on your primary key.

Comment: As I'm using ASP.NET this SQL statement was collected from the SQL profiler- that's why there were some extra columns in there. 

However, I think I solved the problem. 

There were some data already in the table. My Javascript was not collecting the proper guids, so this UPDATE statement was about to update the table so that there would have a conflict with the constraint.

So, the confusion came from the error message itself which talked about inserting the data, even the SQL statement was UPDATE.

Thanks for yout help guys

Answer (score 1):

It looks I solved the problem. It was a conflict with a constraint.

Even the error message talks about *inserting* the duplicate object, *UPDATE* statement's constraint violation error gives the same message.

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 4
>   Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'TUC_LocalizedCountries_1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.LocalizedCountries'. The duplicate key value is (fe73a07d-8505-89c2-450b-4e3f4241f1bb, 935de428-12da-4fd5-9c64-ab87747fa734).